# React component will not receive props passed to it. When rendered with a logical operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jsx

I have this component that will not receive any props I pass into if I have a logical op with it.
I tried rendering it without the conditional and it works fine but once I add it. The component just will not receive the props. any advice? I also don't receive any errors from the compiler

```js
return (
  <>

    {/* progress bar */}
    <ProgressBar percent={percent} />

    {/* {this component will have the props it received} */}
    {<SelectServices display={"any value here"}/>}  

    {/* display booking ui */}

    {/* this component won't */}
    {page === 1 && <SelectServices display={"any value here goes undefined"}/>}
    {page === 2 && <SelectServices />}
    {page === 3 && <SelectServices />}
    {page === 4 && <SelectServices />}
    {page === 5 && <SelectServices />}

  </>
);
```

[image: This is what my console says]

Comment: Copy/pasted your code into a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-component-will-not-receive-props-passed-to-it-when-rendered-with-a-logica-h4dzv) and it renders without issue. Perhaps something isn't correct with your conditions? What are the values of `page`? Do the types match?

Comment: Thank you you're right this was really just a logic error. I forgot I had previously set page to 2. And for the life of my that thought never peeped into my brain.

Comment: Great. Voting to close as "unreproducible or caused by typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's nothing wrong in the approach you are taking. As you are conditionally rendering lot of SelectServices component, have you given the console snapshot for the one with props or is it one of the others? Do you mind posting a codepen line to your problem. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I was so fixated on trying to figure out why my props weren't being passed. That I forgot I had set page to 2. I just knew something was wrong with the condition. By  asking this question I was able to look at my code with a new lens